# How to save date in wince application using VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime

I'm developing inbound application for mobile scanner. This application will update directly to our main database. However I'm having problem saving and recalling datetime value.

First I want to save date as `dd-mmm-yyyy` into datetime field, and  time as `hh:mm` in datetime field. I got error stating "**Arithmetic overflow error converting datetime value**"

Here my code:

```
cmd = New SqlCeCommand("insert into Receiving (Id,PalletNo,Batch,Run,PCode,Qty,AddUser,AddDate) VALUES (@Id,@PalletNo,@Batch,@Run,@PCode,@Qty,@AddUser,@AddDate)", cn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PalletNo", txtPallet.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Batch", Trim(txtBatch.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Run", Trim(txtRun.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCode", Trim(txtPCode.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Val(txtQty.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddUser", txtEmpNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", (ID + 1))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddDate", Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy"))
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store datetime values in DataBase with any format. Just store it and give them the format you need when you are retrieving the value.

If you are using SQL Server, the format for inserting dates manually is `MM/dd/yyyy`, but in your case you can simply use SQL function `getdate()` in you want the actual datetime.